# What are "beer does"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, australian-english

The chorus (one of the variations) of the song Down Under performed by Men at Work goes as follows

> I come from a land down under
>
> Where **beer does** flow and men chunder
>
> Can't you hear, can't you hear the thunder
>
> You better run, you better take cover.

The lyrics' meaning is generally not 100% intelligible (to me, at least), but let's focus on this particular moment: what are "beer does", and why do they flow? Is it something from Aussie English, like "chunder" meaning "vomit" ('cause I take "down under" as a reference to Australia)?

Comment: An archaic form modernised (X doth _verb_) inserted so that the words fit the tune & for reasons of scansion. Yes, [Men at Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_at_Work) are or were an Australian band. The song was a hit 42 years ago, when sexist attitudes were more common than now. 'Men at work' was a warning road sign erected on highways under repair, now replaced by something non-gender-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Does" is the 3rd person present of the verb "do" and not the plural of the noun "doe". So the proper phrase is "does flow", not "beer does".

"Does flow" is an emphatic form of "flows".  In this case, the emphatic form is probably chosen only to fit the verse, and has *no* emphatic meaning.  Thus this line is *identical* in meaning to "Where beer flows, and men chunder". Chunder is indeed Aussie slang for "vomit", but the rest of the lyrics are standard English.

The irony in the song is the contrast between the heroic and the mundane, the etheric and the earthy. - But this is straying far too far into literary criticism.

Answer (score 3):

"Where beer does flow" is similar to say, "a land where honey (or milk) flows", that is a land with an abundance of beer/honey/milk.

In general, poems have more obscure meanings , and it's left to the interpretation of the reader. The website Genius.com tries to explain meanings in songs.

The presence of "does" is so that to force the verses sound better when singing. I think the term in poetry is called *metre*. Often lyrics fill or contract words for this purpose, and thus might not sound common English.